# Laptop for developer

Tags: laptop, development, web-development

can you advice me some good laptops for back end development? 
Primary I need good procesor for running servers like, Geoserver, IIS, and so on (i7 ?) and a lot of RAM (12-16GB or more). I do not know if I need external graphic card, I am using sometimes Photoshop for small design, or photo editing.
For data I need 512GB SSD or more (if HDD, price must be lower for bought custom SSD).

My budget is max 2000$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the [Lenovo ThinkPad P50](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA8TK4C50285).

Here's an overview of the specifications:

- i7-6700HQ (4 Cores/8 Threads) at 2.6GHz (Turbo to 3.5GHz)
- 32GB DDR4 2133MHz RAM
- 1TB SSD
- Quadro M1000M GPU
- $1920

The i7 Should be able to drive a couple servers at once, since it has 8 Threads. 32GB of RAM should be more than enough for multiple running processes. A 1TB SSD should give you low latency, fast R/W, and a large amount of data storage. The Quadro M1000M GPU should be fine for photo editing and driving multiple displays if needed. I believe there are 2 more 2.5" Bays, so you can add more storage in the future if needed.